# How can i select multiple rows from table view and how to get data from that?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can i select multiple rows from a table view and i need to get
that data(Cell) which were selected by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add selected Cell's [indexPath row] to an Array. And use it later.
NSMutableArray* selectedCellsArray; // iVar then somwhere in your implementation

```
selectedCellsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in your tableView didSelectRowAtIndexpath delegate method:

```
[selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[indexPath row]]];
```

your array will have all of selected tableView cells indexPath row.

Comment: I tried with the above code but unable to get the celldata.If the user selects the multiple rows then we need that data .

Answer (score 0):

You can do with your logic and For every select you can change as Checkmark at the cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
           // change this row as selected
          //add the value in an array and use tat at the end
         }
```